# How to convert a recursive function that finds all possible paths in a matrix to an iterative function?

Tags: python, recursion, matrix, iteration, path-finding

I have a function that finds all possible paths from the top left to bottom right cell of a matrix, moving right, down or diagonal to find paths.

Now, I want to convert this to an iterative function so that it can be easier for me to make adjustments later. Does anyone know how I might do this?

```
def findPaths(mat, path, i, j):
 
    (M, N) = (len(mat), len(mat[0]))
 
    # if we have reached the last cell, print the route
    if i == M - 1 and j == N - 1:
        #print('finish')
        print(path + [mat[i][j]])
        return
 
    # include current cell in path

    path.append(mat[i][j])
    
    # move right
    if 0 <= i < M and 0 <= j + 1 < N:
        #print('right',i,j)
        findPaths(mat, path, i, j + 1)
 
    # move down
    if 0 <= i + 1 < M and 0 <= j < N:
        #print('down',i,j)
        findPaths(mat, path, i + 1, j)
    
    # move diagonal
    if 0 <= i + 1 < M and 0 <= j + 1 < N:
        #print('diagonal',i,j)
        findPaths(mat, path, i + 1, j + 1)
    
    # remove current cell from path
    path.pop()
 
 
if __name__ == '__main__':
 
    mat = [
        [1, 2, 6],
        [4, 5, 7],
        [7, 8, 9]
    ]
    
    path = []
 
    # start from (0, 0) cell
    x = y = 0
    
    findPaths(mat, path, x, y)
```

Answer (score 0):

Recursion makes it easier because you can push and pop onto your path list in tandem with the call stack. This is memory-friendly, because the copy to yield a solution only happens at the very end, then the same intermediate path list is reused for all other paths.

As an aside, I'd suggest `yield path[:]` instead of `print` at the terminal node so the caller has freedom to use the result programmatically in addition to printing, making the function more general-purpose. You'll also need `yield from findPaths...` to make this happen.

Also, watch out for indexing into potentially empty lists.

There's probably a combinatoric solution to this particular problem (see [Project Euler #15](https://projecteuler.net/problem=15)), but that doesn't really help with the general case of all paths in a graph so I'm not looking into it.

For a typical dynamic programming problem like this, you could do a bottom-up solution with two loops which would be fantastic for computing the number of results at `dp[-1][-1]`, but isn't as useful for storing a whole list of every possible path at every node, even if you allocate/deallocate lists from no longer useful intermediate states at `i - 2, j - 2`.

The typical pattern for this refactor is an explicit stack that keeps tracks of all the paths. Here's a rewrite of your code alongside the typical iterative version (still room for optimization, consider it a proof-of-concept):

```
def find_paths_rec(mat, x=0, y=0, path=None):
    if not mat or not mat[y]:
        return
    elif not path:
        path = []

    dirs = (1, 0), (0, 1), (1, 1),
    M, N = len(mat), len(mat[y])
    path.append(mat[y][x])

    if y == M - 1 and x == N - 1:
        yield path[:]
    else:
        for xx, yy in dirs:
            xx += x
            yy += y

            if yy < M and xx < N:
                yield from find_paths_rec(mat, xx, yy, path)

    path.pop()

def find_paths_it(mat, x=0, y=0):
    dirs = (1, 1), (0, 1), (1, 0),
    stack = [((x, y), (mat[y][x],))]

    while stack:
        (x, y), path = stack.pop()

        if y == len(mat) - 1 and x == len(mat[y]) - 1:
            yield path
        else:
            for xx, yy in dirs:
                xx += x
                yy += y

                if yy < len(mat) and xx < len(mat[yy]):
                    stack.append(((xx, yy), path + (mat[yy][xx],)))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    from timeit import timeit 

    mat = [
        [1, 2, 6],
        [4, 5, 7],
        [7, 8, 9],
    ]

    for fn in find_paths_it, find_paths_rec:
        print(fn.__name__, timeit(lambda: fn(mat, 0, 0)))

        for path in fn(mat, 0, 0):
            print(path)

        print()
```

Output:

```
find_paths_it 0.9263676
(1, 2, 6, 7, 9)
(1, 2, 5, 7, 9)
(1, 2, 5, 8, 9)
(1, 2, 5, 9)
(1, 2, 7, 9)
(1, 4, 5, 7, 9)
(1, 4, 5, 8, 9)
(1, 4, 5, 9)
(1, 4, 7, 8, 9)
(1, 4, 8, 9)
(1, 5, 7, 9)
(1, 5, 8, 9)
(1, 5, 9)

find_paths_rec 0.9654003
[1, 2, 6, 7, 9]
[1, 2, 5, 7, 9]
[1, 2, 5, 8, 9]
[1, 2, 5, 9]
[1, 2, 7, 9]
[1, 4, 5, 7, 9]
[1, 4, 5, 8, 9]
[1, 4, 5, 9]
[1, 4, 7, 8, 9]
[1, 4, 8, 9]
[1, 5, 7, 9]
[1, 5, 8, 9]
[1, 5, 9]
```